# Can't revoke Google API App Permissions [WEB]

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm creating a Web App that allows users to sign in using their Google Account credentials. I'm using the Google Sign In API to do this.

So far, users can sign in and sign out and grant my app the required permissions. All good. However, I want to give my users the option to disassociate their google account with my app and destroy any data belonging to them.

I've looked through the documentation (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/disconnect), and it only suggests this;

```
var revokeAllScopes = function() {
  auth2.disconnect();
}
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. I can still sign in and sign out without needing to request any permissions for the App again. Am I missing something here, or is my understanding of how this works way off?

Here is the code for signing in and signing out;

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<a href="#" onclick="revokeAllScopes()">Revoke Scopes</a>
<script>
    var revokeAllScopes = function() {
        auth2.disconnect();
    }
    function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I forgot I had declared the `auth2` variable within the signout function, and therefore it wasn't available in the removeAllScopes function. My bad.